# Windows 7: Locked files as a result of logout script (False 'Sharing Violation')

Tags: windows-7, batch, batch-file

I administer several digital whiteboard computers that require calibration of the pens to work properly. Unfortunately, calibration is done on a user basis and isn't stored for the whole computer. Furthermore, the harddrives of these computers are protected against changes as they are used in a secondary school where students like to fiddle with our PCs.

The combination of these factors is an issue as the pen calibration deteriorates over time and all recalibrations are erased by reboots. So I thought up this scheme to persist calibration changes:

a) The system copies the calibration file of the pen **to** a network share when a user logs off. This is done with a bat file that is called through a local group policy:

```
logoff.bat:
attrib -h "%AppData%\path_to_settings.xml"
xcopy "%AppData%\path_to_settings.xml" "\\10.86.1.3\whiteboard_settings\%ComputerName%\" /H /Y /Q /R > nul
attrib -h "\\10.86.1.3\whiteboard_settings\%ComputerName%\settings.xml"
```

b) The system copies the calibration file **from** the network share when the user logs in. This is simply a bat file called by public autostart.

```
logon.bat:
xcopy "\\10.86.1.3\whiteboard_settings\%ComputerName%\settings.xml" "%AppData%\path_to_settings.xml" /H /Y /Q /R > nul
attrib -h "%AppData%\path_to_settings.xml"
```

The attrib -H call is there because there the calibration software doesn't save the calibration in the local file if it is hidden. (However, strangely, calling attrib -H doesn't have an effect on the network share.)

This setup works fine as long as I only log on or log off users. When I reboot the computer, however, the file on the network share is locked and copying or changing it doesn't work: I get a "False 'Sharing Violation'" from xcopy. It looks like the logoff bat script isn't fully executed and some lock remains. Is this to be expected with logoff scripts and reboots? Or is it another issue, maybe with the attrib call?